# Problema com opencv no linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv

Estou fazendo um sistema de monitoramento com Opencv Python via streaming no meu SO Windos 10 roda tudo corretamente por ironia no meu Linux Mate recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro quando tento rodar

> Nonmatching transport in server reply

segue meu código:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.25.179:554/onvif1")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #print(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: E o seu Linux tem acesso a rede do rtsp? (acesso ao IP e porta que apontou)

Comment: Tem outro processo acessando o rtsp no momento no linux?

Answer (score 1):

aconteceu comigo . isso tem a ver com variáveis do sistema.

você pode iniciar assim:

```
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;udp"

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.25.179:554/onvif1", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
```

Aconselho a você instalar o pacote completo do `v4l2` no linux geralmente tbm resolve.